# Programmatically C# remove special characters from HTML source

Tags: c#, postgresql

Issue - I am downloading an excel file from an online service. The problem is that it downloads as an XLS extention, but when you do a Save As its actually a WebPage type HTML. What I have to do is open excel and save as Excel file. When I import the file programmatically to Postgres, the data imports fine no problem. The problem is when clicking the save from PgAdmin and the CSV shows those special characters. They look like foreign characters.

However, lets go back to the online service. If I manually copy the list and paste it into Notepad (which strips those characters)...then copy the list back into an excel file. Then there is no issue.

Question is: How to strip these characters programmatically instead of doing it manually with Notepad?
Example of the issue: Look at the Image. The date time has the special character and also the other cell should say "FILLER 5"
[image]

Comment: @KirkWoll - I added a sample of the data that is showing the characters I want to fix. These characters do NOT show in Postgres...Only when you click Save As to a CSV file.

Comment: Before you go removing characters, it's possible that the right encoding is not being used to handle the file's contents so it's getting mangled. You're going through more than one translation so there's a high probability of that. Figure out why the characters are there, first.

Comment: @madreflection - The problem is from the source, which is the "Excel" file that I download manually. If you do a Save As, it says WebPage. Even if I change it to "Excel Workbook" it still does not resolve my issue. The only way to resolve my issue is to copy the contents from the webpage manually and put them in excel.

Comment: The "Save As" mechanism is saving data that's been interpreted by the browser, so it's already been mangled. Use `HttpClient` to request the *raw* data.

Comment: It's a file behind an authentication page. I would have to figure out a way to automate the login, go to the page, set the calendar and do the HttpClient.